# mmdebstrap - how to add gpg?

Tags: debian, gpg, chroot

Here is the dreaded command:

```
sudo mmdebstrap -v --debug --architectures=riscv64 --include="debian-ports-archive-keyring" sid /tmp/riscv64-chroot "deb [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian-ports/ sid main" "deb [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian-ports/ unreleased main" --aptopt="DPkg::Pre-Invoke {\"sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 84C573CD4E1AFD6C\";};" --aptopt="Debug::RunScripts 'true';"
```

I've tried all combinations and the latest prefix of `[trusted=yes]` brings me a bit further in the progress bu it still fails with:

> W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian-ports sid InRelease: The
>   following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 84C573CD4E1AFD6C Debian
>   Ports Archive Automatic Signing Key (2020)

My question is how to pre-import the gpg keys so it won't fail.

Answer (score 1):

"apt-key list" shows me that the key has expired recently:

```
pub   rsa4096 2018-12-26 [SC] [expired: 2020-01-31]
      1177 213F 7B9E F1C5 280C  FEEA 84C5 73CD 4E1A FD6C
                                     ^^^^...
```

and I would guess that the "debian-ports" i.e. backports has not been updated/signed since then?